# Iterate through a column

Tags: python, pandas

This is a very basic question : I want to iterate through a dataframe column which I extracted in a list "unique" and write each of the visits between quotation marks and separated by Space into a cell in an excel file, this code just return the last Value :

```
unique = Contains['VISIT'].unique().tolist()

i = 0
visit_id = []
sizeofList = len(unique) 

while i < sizeofList :
        g = unique[i]
        visit_id = '"'+g+'"'
print(visit_id) 
i += 1

d = {'Visitname': [visit_id]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df.to_excel('Visits.xlsx', index= False ) 

Output : 

"VISIT 10"
"VISIT 10.1"
"VISIT 10.2"

Visitname
"VISIT 10.2"
```

Comment: That won't work, you'll get stuck in an infinite loop because `i += 1` is outside of the loop. However, you shouldn't really be iterating dfs anyway; do you have an example input and output?

Comment: Actually, a lot of stuff won't work because it seems to be outside of the loop you intended

Comment: Hi @roganjosh  , the input is the  "unique"  list which is ['VISIT 10', 'VISIT 10.1', 'VISIT 10.2']

Comment: You're basically wanting to write unique values formatted in a certain way as a single column to a worksheet then?

Comment: @ Jon Clements♦ that's right

Comment: Eg... does `Contains['VISIT'].drop_duplicates().apply('"{}"'.format).rename('Visitname').to_excel('Visits.xlsx')` do what you're after?

Comment: Thank you @Jon Clements♦, this works well but I need to write the values into one unique cell , your code write every values in a different Row

Comment: `visit_list = ', '.join(df['VISIT'].apply('"{}"'.format).unique())`, then export `visit_list` to Excel?

Comment: @Shahine your desired string to output then - does doing: `Contains['VISIT'].drop_duplicates().map('"{}"'.format).str.cat(sep=' ')` get you that?

Comment: Hi @Jon Clements♦ thank you so much for your code. works well !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a much simpler way to do this using `apply` but to keep with the way you have it here.

You haven't added anything to your array `visit_id` so that's why you are only getting one value.

Try this.

```
unique = Contains['VISIT'].unique().tolist()

i = 0
visit_id = []
sizeofList = len(unique) 

while i < sizeofList :
        g = unique[i]
        visit_id.append('"'+g+'"')
        i += 1

print(visit_id) 

df = pd.DataFrame({'Visitname': [visit_id]})

df.to_excel('Visits.xlsx', index= False )
```

Comment: I changed visit_id.append('"'+g+'"')   to  visit_id.append(g)
because there is extra " and the Excel file contains ['VISIT 10', 'VISIT 10.1', 'VISIT 10.2']   I need to get rid of the Brackets [ ]